# objective-c: creating a server method

Tags: mysql, objective-c, ios

Currently I am able to retrieve data from a MySQL db by using HTTP GET and an NSURL connection, but I need to know how to encapsulate this action into a method. Could somebody inform me of how to put the following code into a method so that I can call it throughout my app, and also so that I can show a UIActivityIndicator while the process is underway?

```
//somethign like this?
-(void)getDataFromServer:(NSString *)url{
//enter code here

}
```

My current server request: I am using this in didselectrowforindexpath, so that the following stuff is done whenever somebody selects a cell. The issue is that I keep re-using this same code in several different methods, so I assume that it is bad practice to keep copying/pasting this code rather than having a method.

```
// retrieve data
NSString *buildURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://myurl.com"];

// begin query
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:buildURL];
NSError *e;
NSString *jsonreturn = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&e];

NSLog(@"jsonreturn: %@",jsonreturn);

NSData *jsonData = [jsonreturn dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
NSError *error = nil;
```

**EDIT:**
Much better way to do this, which I just implemented, is to use ASIHTTPRequest. The library provides for all the needs which I was trying to accomplish with the method above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take your whole second code block and put it inside the `{}` of the first code block.  You probably want to return that `jsonData` variable instead of `void`, though.

Comment: but where should I put my method? in a separate class so that I can call the method throughout the app?

Comment: That sounds reasonable.  You just need to make sure the object in question is accessible by everyone who wants to call the method.  Your application delegate might be a good place, for example.  It will be pretty design-dependent.  You can also write regular C-style functions in Objective-C if you would prefer.

Comment: also how do I specificy that I want to return JSONData? -(NSData)getDatafromServer:(NSString *)URL{ ... return JSONData}

Comment: `NSData *` probably, but yes.

Comment: could you explain how I would show a UIActiviyIndicator when my method here is retreiving data? I think the following link has a solution, but does it look right? [link](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54985-problem-showing-uialertview.html)

Comment: Seems reasonable, did you try it?

Comment: I don't understand where to put that code though...Should it be in the app delegate. and if so how would I call the startProcess? just [appDelegateObject startprocess];

Comment: I'll definitely try it but I just don't know where to put the code